# Write a script which prints all 10 arguments which have been passed to it. UNIX TERMINAL

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

Hi guys i am trying to answer the following question but I'm having a hard time to solve it :

> Write a script which prints all 10 arguments which have been passed to it. Once the script has printed the arguments, shift the arguments by 2 and print them all again

here is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "\$1 is now $1"
shift 
echo "\$2 is now $2"
shift 
echo "\$3 is now $3"
echo "\$4 is now $4"
echo "\$5 is now $5"
echo "\$6 is now $6"
echo "\$7 is now $7"
echo "\$8 is now $8"
echo "\$9 is now $9"
echo "\${10} is now ${10}"
```

and here is my code in unix terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "\$1 is now $1"
shift 
echo "\$2 is now $2"
shift 
echo "\$3 is now $3"
echo "\$4 is now $4"
echo "\$5 is now $5"
echo "\$6 is now $6"
echo "\$7 is now $7"
echo "\$8 is now $8"
echo "\$9 is now $9"
echo "\${10} is now ${10}"
```

thank you

Comment: and your "this problem" is ...?

Comment: You posted the same identical code twice.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way

```
x=0
for i in "$@"; do echo "\$$((++x)) is $i"; done
shift
shift
x=0
for i in "$@"; do echo "\$$((++x)) is now $i";done
```

Comment: +1, but not entirely correct: Need to quote the expansion of `$i` to prevent glob expansions -- if you're passed `'*'` as an argument, you don't want to print a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point, looks like gniourf_gniourf beat me to editing though.